# Creating Jest test for React-Native.Keyboard listener

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a functional component which includes the following code.

```
export const FunctionalComponent = (props: ComponentProps) => {
    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState<number>();
    const [prefix, setPrefix] = useState<string>();
    const [id, setId] = useState<string>();
    const screenHeight = useWindowDimensions().height;
  
    const PIXELS_NOT_AVAILABLE_ON_ANDROID = 370;
    const PIXELS_NOT_AVAILABLE_ON_IOS = 387;
  
    const pixelsNotAvailableForEmptyTrailerList = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? PIXELS_NOT_AVAILABLE_ON_IOS : PIXELS_NOT_AVAILABLE_ON_ANDROID;
    const [maxHeight, setMaxHeight] = useState<number>(Math.round(screenHeight - pixelsNotAvailableForEmptyTrailerList));

    const onKeyboardShown = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
      setMaxHeight(Math.round(screenHeight - pixelsNotAvailableForEmptyTrailerList - e.endCoordinates.height));
    };
  
    const onKeyboardHidden = () => {
      setMaxHeight(Math.round(screenHeight - pixelsNotAvailableForEmptyTrailerList));
    };
  
    const getKeyboardShowEvent = () => (Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'keyboardWillShow' : 'keyboardDidShow');
    const getKeyboardHideEvent = () => (Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'keyboardWillHide' : 'keyboardDidHide');
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const keyboardDidShowListener: EmitterSubscription = Keyboard.addListener(getKeyboardShowEvent(), e => onKeyboardShown(e));
      const keyboardDidHideListener: EmitterSubscription = Keyboard.addListener(getKeyboardHideEvent(), () => onKeyboardHidden());
      return () => {
        keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
        keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
      };
    },
    []);
  

    return (
      <View style={ styles.container }>
        ...stuff
      </View>
    );
  };
```

I need coverage on the `setMaxHeight` function calls in the `onKeyboardShown` and `onKeyboardHidden` functions and I need coverage on the `keyboardDidShowListener` and `keyboardDidHideListener` functions.

I tried adding the following code to my test to mock `useWindowDimensions`, `Keyboard` and `Platform`.

```
const mockAddListenerReturn = { remove: jest.fn() };

jest.mock('react-native', () => ({
  useWindowDimensions: jest.fn({ height: 800 }),
  Keyboard: {
    addListener: jest.fn(() => mockAddListenerReturn),
  },
  Platform: {
    OS: 'android',
  },
  EmitterSubscription: jest.requireActual('react-native').EmitterSubscription,
  FlatList: jest.requireActual('react-native').FlatList,
  KeyboardEvent: jest.requireActual('react-native').KeyboardEvent,
  TouchableOpacity: jest.requireActual('react-native').TouchableOpacity,
  View: jest.requireActual('react-native').View,
  render: jest.requireActual('react-native').render,
}));
```

Unfortunately this causes issues with a utilities test file we import into our tests and I get the following error.

> ● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')

  1 | import React from 'react';
> 2 | import { MenuProvider } from 'react-native-popup-menu';
    | ^
  3 | import { render as baseRender } from '@testing-library/react-native';
  4 | import { ThemeContextProvider } from '@jbhunt-ds/mobile-theme';
  5 | import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

  at node_modules/react-native-popup-menu/src/Backdrop.js:50:27
  at node_modules/react-native-popup-menu/build/rnpm.js:4:66
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-popup-menu/build/rnpm.js:5:3)
  at Object.<anonymous> (test/utilities.js:2:1)
```

I don't understand why mocking react-native components causes an issue with importing `MenuProvider` from `react-native-popup-menu`.